# JSOUP extract data from <select name=...>

Tags: java, html, select, jsoup

here's an html code. I want to print "Color:" and various color options present. And somehow I want it by using "select name=att1" that means by name tag of select.

```
<div class="box-body">

    <div id="attributeInputs" class="attribute-inputs" data-defcolor="Palm">

        <div class="row thinpad-top att1row">
            <div class="small-24 columns">
                <label for="att1_BA0FEDC6-8BF1-11E4-B816-87E377679EE2">Color:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="small-24 columns">
                <select name="att1" id="att1_BA0FEDC6-8BF1-11E4-B816-87E377679EE2">
                    <option value="">Please Select Color</option>
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>
                    <option value="Palm">Palm</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I've tried so many jsoup tags. But I'm not able to get required output

I want output something like this:

```
Please Select Color:
Black 

Palm
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

This code will extract the elements inside the select tag and option tag

```
 String html="<div class=\"box-body\">\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "    <div id=\"attributeInputs\" class=\"attribute-inputs\" data-defcolor=\"Palm\">\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "        <div class=\"row thinpad-top att1row\">\n" +
                        "            <div class=\"small-24 columns\">\n" +
                        "                <label for=\"att1_BA0FEDC6-8BF1-11E4-B816-87E377679EE2\">Color:</label>\n" +
                        "            </div>\n" +
                        "            <div class=\"small-24 columns\">\n" +
                        "                <select name=\"att1\" id=\"att1_BA0FEDC6-8BF1-11E4-B816-87E377679EE2\">\n" +
                        "                    <option value=\"\">Please Select Color</option>\n" +
                        "                    <option value=\"Black\">Black</option>\n" +
                        "                    <option value=\"Palm\">Palm</option>\n" +
                        "                </select>\n" +
                        "            </div>";

                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                Elements links = doc.select("select option");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    String linkText = link.text();
                    System.out.println(linkText);
                }
```

Comment: but there can be more options tags .so it's better to take only nested option tags inside select tag